# How to get partial command line to file

Tags: command-line, bash, sh

I want to save some text (partial) in command line to file,

This my command line for example :

```
sudo gammu sendsms TEXT 08539032xxxx -text "Testing sms dari aplikasi gammu modem" >> log.txt
```

it will produces log.txt file with content like this :

```
Sending SMS 1/1....waiting for network answer..OK, message reference=145
```

How to make the result to :

```
08539032xxxx sending SMS 1/1....waiting for network answer..OK, message reference=145
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating a function:

```
#!/bin/bash

function mygammu()
{
    sudo gammu sendsms TEXT "$1" -text "$2" | xargs "$1"
}
```

Put it in your `.bashrc`, then use the command like this:

```
mygammu "08539032xxxx" "Testing sms dari aplikasi gammu modem" >> logfile
```

the output would be:

```
08539032xxxx Sending SMS 1/1....waiting for network answer..OK, message reference=145
```